# Replacement for chained if-statements

Tags: sml

I'm new to SML and I'm at the point where I can write functional code but I'm unsure of whether there's a more proper or idiomatic way to do things. SML only allows value constructors in patterns, so a case statement doesn't work below. SML also doesn't allow multiple else-if statements.

The following works, but has an ugly triply-nested for-loop. Is there a more idiomatic way to write the following code?

```
datatype coins = penny | nickle | dime | quarter;

fun valueToCoins 0 = nil
  | valueToCoins x =
      if x >= 25
      then quarter::valueToCoins(x-25)
      else
           if x >= 10
           then dime::valueToCoins(x-10)
           else
                if x >= 5
                then nickle::valueToCoins(x-5)
                else penny::valueToCoins(x-1);
```

Comment: I don't really see what's wrong with this, other than weird formatting. Why indent every new if expression?

Comment: To add to @glennsl's comment, since you tagged `ocaml` you might want to look at using `ocamlformat` if you try an OCaml version of this, especially if your editor can integrate it (like Vim, Emacs, VScode AFAIK). That would show you a flat formatting for it. - Formatting aside, in OCaml sometimes it's clearer to use pattern matching with conditional `when` clauses instead of chained conditions. It might help here.

Comment: @glennsl Well, I don't really know if anything is wrong with it, or that the formatting was weird. Maybe to satisfy the question-answer format I should have phrased the question, "Is this a weird way to do this?"

Comment: Also, there are `nested if`(s). I can't find any `...triply-nested for-loop...` when I read the OP. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments have addressed this, but really you've done the right thing. You just need to format it properly and it looks reasonable.

```
datatype coins = penny | nickle | dime | quarter;

fun valueToCoins 0 = nil
  | valueToCoins x =
      if x >= 25 then 
        quarter :: valueToCoins(x - 25)
      else if x >= 10 then 
        dime :: valueToCoins(x - 10)
      else if x >= 5 then 
        nickle :: valueToCoins(x - 5)
      else 
        penny :: valueToCoins(x - 1);
```